# BigQuery not returning missing NULL rows in LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can we get BigQuery to return the rows in a LEFT JOIN which exist in TABLE A but are NULL in TABLE B?

The below returns no rows when I run it, even though there are values in table A which are not in table B

```
-- find missing users. return rows which exist in A but not in B
select          a.user_id
from            table_a a  
left outer join table_b b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
where           b.user_id is null
```

Comment: Your code is correct so your issue is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work, based on what you say.  However, you can also use `NOT EXISTS` directly:

```
select a.user_id
from  table_a a  
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_b b 
                  where a.user_id = b.user_id 
                 );
```